# If someone's house is leaking can I say 'he is leaking'?

Tags: sentence-meaning

If someone's house is leaking can I say 'he is leaking'? His house is leaking sounds alright but I d like to know if 'he is leaking' is also possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Nope. "He is leaking" means that he himself (as in his body) is leaking something.

Comment: Yes, it means that he is incontinent.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey He could have been stabbed or shot . . .

Comment: Yes, of course.